# Can we bind value directly in vuejs like, v-bind:value=" 'India' "

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Can we bind value directly like

```
v-bind:value="'India'"
```

Suppose I have field,

```
 <input id="country" type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      name="country" placeholder="country" v-bind:value="'India'" v-model="fields.country">
```

throw error

> v-bind:value="'India'" conflicts with v-model on the same
> element because the latter already expands to a value binding
> internally

Using laravel 7.x and vue 2.5

Comment: Are you looking for the default text in the input to be India until the user types something else in?

Comment: How is `fields` defined ?

Comment: data() {
     return { 
       fields: {},
  } 
}

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to bind value in input field when view is loaded

Comment: Value is already binded by the v-model, set the value "India" at fields.country.

Comment: but this happen at run time, right?

Comment: yes, as long as you have defined it at data, it will be reactive and change at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `fields.country` an initial value. Notice in order to make `fields.country` reactive, you also need to declare `country` property in `fields`:

```
data () {
  return {
    fields: {
      country: 'India'
    }
  }
}
```

No need for `v-bind:value` in your template:

```
 <input id="country" type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      name="country" placeholder="country" v-model="fields.country">
```

Comment: What do you mean runtime ? it happens when the component is first initiated. Any update to `fields.country` will update the value in both data and view.

Comment: I have, data() { return { fields: {}, } }

Comment: Change it to, data() { return { fields: { country : "India"} } }

Comment: and if I make fields with initialization, then what will happen when there are many input fields.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can update those fields however you want. Just remember to declare them in your data if you want them to be reactive.

Comment: @Sujay you can set defaults of your form input at data, ex: ```data() { return { fields: { country : "India", country_phone_code: 91, city: "New Delhi"} } } ``` as @Psidom said, put them at data, so they can have reactive properties.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. V-model already binds the `fields.country` value to the input.
If you want a default value to be defined before, try assigning it to `fields.country` like `fields.country = "India"`